# TableView does not load all the records in simulator of iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I created the following table view:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7w9zlyxwa6mul7/TestTable.zip?dl=0

However it does not load all the rows of the data on the table.

Can anybody please advise me how to load all the data in this.

Comment: What's your problem ? I tried all data are loading till 'U'

Comment: Please post your code & describe what error you are getting.. No need to share entire code.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code directly in your post. Also describe precisely what you expect it to do, and what it actually does.

Comment: @AjayKumar, My problem is I can see only till M in iPhone Simulator. I can not see more than that. That is my problem.

Comment: @NileshPatel  I am not getting any error. Data is present till U. I can not see beyond M. on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your questions I suppose one of these might be your actual question -

- If you want the tableView to display all cells, then set the height for cells to smaller values using UITabeleViewDelegate method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`. By default, the cell height is 44. So at max only 11 rows will be visible (only till M).
- If you are saying that when the UITableView calls `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` only till M, then the answer is that it is the default functionality of iOS. iOS handles all the visible cell data whenever needed. So all the data is loaded dynamically while scrolling making use of the previous cells.